# Is there a way to represent in java a javascript variable that can be either an int or an array of ints?

Tags: java

Look at the deferLoading variable in the next to block, I need to map that variable in java, what is the best way to achieve this in java?

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php",
      "deferLoading": [ 57, 100 ],
      "search": {
        "search": "my_filter"
      }
    } );



$('#example').dataTable( {
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php",
  "deferLoading": 57
} );
```

Comment: Not as such, since Java is strongly typed, but you can just define it as always being an `int[]`, since there's nothing stopping you from having an array with only one element.

Comment: It is possible depending on the library your using but without more information its hard to be of any help.

Comment: @ug_ what library allows you to do this? What other information would be important to provide?

Comment: @George I know GSON and Jackson both provide ways to customize the serialization works for specific fields. GSON provides this functionality through the `TypeAdapter` class and Jackson uses `JsonDeserializer`. These are just 2 libraries out of who knows how many. If you could post your Java code where you deseralize the JSON it would be very helpful in providing an awnser.